# vue.js -Imported css files getting mixed up while routing from one page to another

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have two components in views folder namely Home.vue and Register.vue
I have imported separate css files for each component

Home.vue

```
<style scoped>
  @import "../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css";
  @import "../assets/css/mainpages/style.css";
  @import "../assets/css/mainpages/custom.css";  
  @import "../assets/css/mainpages/css/plugins.min.css";  

</style>
```

Register.vue

```
<style  scoped>

  @import "../assets/css/main.css";
  @import "../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css";
  @import "../assets/css/theme.css";

</style>
```

I am using vue router to route. When routing from Home.vue to Register.vue everything is good.
But when i try to route back from Register.vue to Home.vue the css properties imported in Registered.vue gets applied to Home.vue

What may be the reason for such a behavior.

I have added scope to all style tags, but it is also not working.

Comment: Try to add scope only to those CSS which are unique for the given component - and leave the rest of the CSS (which is supposedly global - e.g. the Bootstrap) unscoped. Or better yet - import the global CSS in `App.vue` or even `main.js` - and define your scoped CSS directly into your Single-File component rather than separate CSS file.

Comment: OK I will do that. Actually I am trying to integrate an admin section with login to already existing pages. So both are designed seperatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the way you are importing external files as scoped ones :

Home.vue

```
<style scoped src="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"></style>
<style scoped src="../assets/css/mainpages/style.css"></style>
<style scoped src="../assets/css/mainpages/custom.css"></style>
<style scoped src="../assets/css/mainpages/css/plugins.min.css"></style>
```

The same applies for register.vue

Thanks to Filip Jerga for the answer

Comment: I tried the same but this does not see to work for me. Following is the code I have: `<style scoped src="~/assets/css/drawflow.css"></style>

<style> my other styles </style>`

Comment: ~ may not work try ../ instead